# Access static objective C method in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, bridging

In my Obj-C files, I have this static member and getter :

```
//******* DBASplashViewController.m ********
static SWRevealViewController *staticRVC;
+ (SWRevealViewController*)currentSWRevealViewController
{
    return staticRVC;
}

//******* DBASplashViewController.h ********
+ (SWRevealViewController*)currentSWRevealViewController;
```

In my swift code, I have an error on this line :

```
let SWVC = DBASplashViewController.currentSWRevealViewController
```

`Error :
*DBASplashViewController has no member currentSWRevealViewController*`

EDIT :

This is my bridging file :

```
 #import "DBASplashViewController.h"
```

As you can see, DBASplashViewController is perfectly interpreted by XCode, but not the static method :

[image]

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Refer my answer on the below link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37859446/instantiate-objective-c-view-controller-in-swift/37860566#37860566

Comment: i have the bridge, DBASplashViewController is recognized, but currentSWRevealViewController is not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long investigation, it appears i have a missing import in my bridging header.

`DBASplashViewController.currentSWRevealViewController()` must return a object of type SWRevealViewController.

It appears i have forgotten to have the line in my bridging header :

```
#import "SWRevealViewController.h"
```

Since the return type is define on Swift part, i can access to my static variable.

Answer (score 0):

Take note that `currentSWRevealViewController` is a method, not a property, and if you want to execute it you should use the following notation, basically adding a pair of round brackets. Otherwise this will return the type of the function that's actually a *(function)*.

```
let SWVC = DBASplashViewController.currentSWRevealViewController()
```

Assuming that you have a correct Bridging Header and the `staticRVC` variable works as expected, this will work.

Comment: with        

let SWVC = DBASplashViewController.currentSWRevealViewController()
I have the same error

Comment: @Imbru what your Bridging Header file looks like? I just tried to replicate your issue and I was able to make it work perfectly, check the .zip project here http://jmp.sh/wXYRfn5

Comment: i have this line in my bridging header : #import "DBASplashViewController.h". DBASplashViewController is recognized. I check your sample project

Comment: I don't see any difference between both code and I still don't understand why I can't access to my static method