# Notification action open view without Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I'm doing an app which opens a detail view from a push notification.
In my AppDelegate I'm opening the view, but the view doesn't have a navigation controller.

Then I think that my solution is use the method `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier`
to handle the navigation controller, I'm not sure if this is the solution, but here is the question of the title...

My class `SlideNavigationController` is Objective-C, and when I use the method

```
let rootVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).
instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SlideNavigationController") as! SlideNavigationController
```

I get the error:

> warning: could not load any Objective-C class information. This will significantly reduce the quality of type information available.

Any idea? Sorry for my English, edits are welcome! Thanks

The problem with my UIController is solved. Here is my code:

```
           let rootViewController = self.window!.rootViewController as! UINavigationController
            let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let targerView = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("view_place_detail") as! VCPlaceDetailTour
            targerView.placeId = aps as String
            rootViewController.pushViewController(targerView, animated: false)
```

Comment: What's an "Objetive View Controller"?

Comment: A view controller with Objetive C code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You can do with this code.

```
let rootViewController = self.window!.rootViewController as! UINavigationController
let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let targerView = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("view Identifier") as! PromotionDetailsVC
rootViewController.pushViewController(targerView, animated: false)
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: what is EasyExtension?

Comment: EasyExtension is my Custom class with Generics<T> using for get value for Json like get any option value can get easily with this function by passing JSON and Key.

Comment: And thanxx if you need that code i can share with you.

Comment: Perfect! I was able to open my landing view using rootController but if the app was open in other view, my landing view was not opened. The other solution opened the landing page without navigation bar.... 
So with your solution I always open the landing view with the navigation bar.

Thanks @AnandNimje

Answer (score 2):

You can programatically create a navigation Controller and set the desired view controller as its rootViewController of the navigation controller and then set navigation controller as windows rootViewController.

eg :

```
let rootVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SlideNavigationController") as! SlideNavigationController
let window = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow
window.rootViewController = rootVC
```

Same is expalined in this link too : [set initial viewcontroller in appdelegate - swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26753925/set-initial-viewcontroller-in-appdelegate-swift)

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Pushing a navigation controller is not supported' :(

Comment: rootVC is a navigation controller I believe, then you have to directly set it as your root vie controller

Comment: Also in your storyboard set the root view controller of your navigation controller

Answer (score 1):

You must need to create a bridging header to use objective c controllers in the swift project.

Follow the link below for information on creating bridging header.

[How to find path of Bridging-Header.h - Swift, Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34627082/how-to-find-path-of-bridging-header-h-swift-xcode/34627382#34627382)

After that you must import the .h files of controllers in the bridging header file.

Now you can easily use your objective c view controller in swift project.

Comment: I imported "SlideNavigationController.h" but the error persist.